Firebase Bom and Gradle Plugin
I realised that even though I'm using Firebase BoM, I will still need to update the versions of the Gradle plugins (Crashlytics, Performance, App Distribution) whenever I update the BoM.
Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way that allows me to declare only the BOM version in my libs.versions.toml?
libs.versions.toml
[versions]
firebaseBom = "33.0.0"
firebaseAppDistributionPlugin = "5.0.0"
firebaseCrashlyticsPlugin = "3.0.1"
firebasePerfPlugin = "1.4.2"

[libraries]
firebase-bom = { module = "com.google.firebase:firebase-bom", version.ref = "firebaseBom" }
firebase-analytics-ktx = { module = "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx" }
firebase-crashlytics-ktx = { module = "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx" }
firebase-messaging-ktx = { module = "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx" }
firebase-perf-ktx = { module = "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf-ktx" }

[plugins]
firebase-appdistribution = { id = "com.google.firebase.appdistribution", version.ref = "firebaseAppDistributionPlugin" }
firebase-crashlytics = { id = "com.google.firebase.crashlytics", version.ref = "firebaseCrashlyticsPlugin" }
firebase-perf = { id = "com.google.firebase.firebase-perf", version.ref = "firebasePerfPlugin" }

Project's build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.firebase.appdistribution) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.firebase.crashlytics) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.firebase.perf) apply false
}

App's build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.firebase.appdistribution)
    alias(libs.plugins.firebase.crashlytics)
    alias(libs.plugins.firebase.perf)
}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform(libs.firebase.bom))
    implementation(libs.firebase.analytics.ktx)
    implementation(libs.firebase.crashlytics.ktx) { isTransitive = true }
    implementation(libs.firebase.perf.ktx)
}


Of the versions you list under [versions], you only ever use the firebaseBom version in the code.  Why do you think the other SDK versions need to be updated (since they never get used)?

@DougStevenson nice catch, it was the wrong code I posted. updated my question

@Alex Mamo, please learn about acceptance.

realised is British English which is acceptable in my part of the world.
the problem has nothing to do with android-library. my intention is to address the gradle plugin part


@YouQi I'm not sure I understood. What about English? BEsides that, the BOM versions don't cover the plugins, right? Only the libraries.

@AlexMamo if you forgot what you did, you corrected the spelling in my question which isn't a mistake to begin with. also added the wrong tag. 2. gradle plugin does release as part of the bom if you checkout the release notes https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android. if you think it can't be done and no elaboration required then you are not the person I'm seeking to answer the question. that's not the ideal goal of using bom afaic. we can do better.


I just used the autocorrect plugin. 2. The libraries and the plugins are two different things.


When you're using the Firebase Android BoM, you don't have to specify individual library versions when you declare Firebase library dependencies in your libs.versions.toml file. As I can see in your file, you already do that, which is correct.
On the other hand, when you declare Firebase App Distribution, Firebase Crashlytics, or Firebase Performance Monitoring plugins you have to declare the versions explicitly. The BOM versions work only for libraries, not for plugins.
Besides that, you can now depend on the main modules instead of the KTX modules. This means that there is no need to specify -ktx for the Firebase dependencies:
[libraries]
firebase-bom = { module = "com.google.firebase:firebase-bom", version.ref = "firebaseBom" }
firebase-analytics-ktx = { module = "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics" }
firebase-crashlytics-ktx = { module = "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics" }
firebase-messaging-ktx = { module = "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging" }
firebase-perf-ktx = { module = "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf" }

If you need, you can still find a list of all KTX modules and their versions at the bottom of the table.

Or you can do it like this:
[versions]
firebase = "X.X.X"

[libraries]
firebase-bom = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-bom", version.ref = "firebase" }
firebase-analytics-ktx = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-analytics" }
firebase-crashlytics-ktx = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-crashlytics" }


